# Running the windows service for every 5 Min

Tags: c#, windows-services

I had created a windows service & Done with successful installation.
I had observed that even though the installation was done, but the service is not showing in the list of services.msc also How could I make the service the to run for every 5 min of interval.

Worked upto the part of installation of the service.

```
       public partial class FeedbcakSMSToDCService : ServiceBase
    {
        DBBase obj = new DBBase();

        Thread threadPRSender;
        string fileName = "D:\\FeedbackSMSlog.txt";
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        System.Timers.Timer TimerObj = new System.Timers.Timer();
        FeedBackSMSToDCHandler feedbackSmstoDcHandler = null;
        EventLog m_EventLog = new EventLog();
        ThreadStart threadSender = null;
        FeedBackSMSToDCHandler FB = new FeedBackSMSToDCHandler();
        public FeedbcakSMSToDCService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            feedbackSmstoDcHandler = new FeedBackSMSToDCHandler();
            threadSender = new ThreadStart(ProcessSMSToDC);
            threadPRSender = new Thread(threadSender);

        }

        static void Main()
        {

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new FeedbcakSMSToDCService()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\FeedbackSMSlog.txt", "Service started on : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                   FileStream fs= File.Create(fileName);
                    fs.Close();
                    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\FeedbackSMSlog.txt", "Service started on : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                //FB.ProcessSMS();
                //SetTimeInterval();
                //timer.Interval =Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerInterval"].ToString());
                timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5 * 60 * 1000);
                timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
                timer.Start();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Source = "On Service Start";

                OASIS.Utility.ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
            }
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            FB.ProcessSMS();
            timer.Start();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"D:\FeedbackSMSlog.txt", "Service stopped on : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

            //TimerObj.Enabled = false;
           timer.Stop();
           threadPRSender = null;
        }
        private void timer_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


                timer.Stop();
                if (threadPRSender.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (threadPRSender.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted
                    || threadPRSender.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped
                    || threadPRSender.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Aborted
                    || !threadPRSender.IsAlive)
                {

                    threadSender = new ThreadStart(ProcessSMSToDC);
                    threadPRSender = new Thread(threadSender);
                    threadPRSender.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ERP\Live\Background Service\Calendar\AttendanceLog.txt", "timer_Tick error : " + ex.StackTrace.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                ex.Source = "Timer Tick error";
                OASIS.Utility.ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
            }
        }



        public void ProcessSMSToDC()
        {
            try
            {
                feedbackSmstoDcHandler = new FeedBackSMSToDCHandler();
                feedbackSmstoDcHandler.ProcessSMS();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Source = "SMS Sent To DC";
                OASIS.Utility.ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ERP\Live\Background Service\Feedback\SmsSendToDC.txt", "Error while ProcessSMS : " + ex.StackTrace.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void SetTimeInterval()
        {
            try
            {
                timer.Start();                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ERP\Live\Background Service\Feedback\SMSToDCLog.txt", "Error while setting time interval : " + ex.StackTrace.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: FYI, Instead of doing math, you could use a `Timespan` object to get the milliseconds: `new System.Timers.Timer(Timespan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds)`

Comment: [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) with a Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => System.Console.WriteLine("STATIC TASK"), Hangfire.Cron.MinuteInterval(5));

Comment: Does anything use the `timer_Tick` method? Is that relevant to this question?

Comment: In your `Timer_Elapsed` method, you stop the timer, perform the work, then start the timer again. If you remove the starting and stopping parts, then the additional time it takes to do the work wouldn't be added to the overall time between executions. What is the problem you're currently seeing?

Comment: if it was me i'd a scheduled task rather than a service - much simpler

Comment: Services are not designed to be spun up every 5 minutes

Comment: If you need to run your service every 5 min you can try https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html. Your service will be running, but it will perform the job every 5 min(or how you configure it).